# To and fro auto scroll LineChart in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

First of all, MPAndroidChart is a great Library. 
I implemented a LineChart and everything went like a breeze. I want to make my LineChart auto scroll to and from to both the extreme points. How can I achieve that?

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(size);
mChart.moveViewToX(valueX);
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please check [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
  chart.moveViewToAnimated(chart.data.entryCount - NUMBER_OF_MONTH_DATA_TO_SHOW, chart.centerOfView.y, chart.axisLeft.axisDependency, 3000);
```